# Stuck on a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I seem to have backed myself up into a corner with this. I'm sure that the answer is going to make me want to smack a brick against my head, but I'm not all that good with regex just yet. So, here goes.

I need to modify this regex so that it fails if it finds any occurances of pound signs. (#)

My current regex is this;

```
/^[A-Za-z\.\-\_\s]{1,80}$/i
```

I tried a number of variations such as;

```
/[^#]^[A-Za-z\.\-\_\s]{1,80}$/i
/^[[^#]A-Za-z\.\-\_\s]{1,80}$/i
/^[A-Za-z\.\-\_\s^#]{1,80}$/i
```

None of which work. Can anyone offer any advise, please?

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with your question. That regex will *already* fail if it finds any occurrence of `#`, because it requires that the string consist of between 1 and 80 letters, dots, hyphens, underscores, and/or white-space characters.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I thought so also. The way I am trying to use it is that it will be ajax real-time field validation. Yet whenever I type anything invalid and then dump a pound sign on the end, it suddenly says it's okay. So, I thought, "well, maybe the pound sign is being misinterpreted by the regex" or something. So, I was right all along then, huh?

Comment: If you post the entirety of the field-validation code, you may get more useful answers.

Comment: I would, but it's a bit spread out across 3 files if that's okay. That was the only reason I didn't to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original regex should work, because `#` isn't in the list of characters you specified for the class. You don't need to add anything, it already fails if there's a `#` in there.

Comment: Thank you Kolink. As I just mentioned to ruakh, I thought it should work also. Strange how it's acting this way.

Comment: It seems to be working now. I'm not precisely sure what I did wrong originally, but it seems fine now. I apologize for the rather brief code sample. As I mentioned to ruakh, I thought it might be a bit much to paste everything here for what seemed like simple regex related issue. You were correct though that it did what you said. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use two regexes:

```
/^[A-Za-z\.\-\_\s]{1,80}$/i
```

Then filter your input so that you keep only what does NOT match this regex:

```
/#/
```

It's far easier to match on patterns that you want to filter out (and then ignoring the matching strings instead of ignoring the complement) than it is to try to construct an "inverse" regex. And there's no reason why you should try to fit everything into one regex.

Comment: Oops, I get the dunce award for not realizing that the problem is already solved. Way to go Kolink.

Comment: +1. I'm not clear on exactly what the OP has in mind here, but your advice that "there's no reason why you should try to fit everything into one regex" is relevant to anyone trying to do this sort of thing.